# Display precise time remaining

Tags: unity-game-engine, countdowntimer, unityscript

I have the following code and I want to add miliSeconds var so it would display something like this:

minutes : seconds : miliSeconds

2 : 35 : 98

Time.time is the time elapsed from app begin, update function gets called every frame.

```
var startTime:float;
var timeRemaining:float;

var minutes:int;
var seconds:int;
var miliSeconds:int;
var timeStr:String;

function Start () {
    startTime = 130.0;
}

function Update () {
    timeRemaining = startTime - Time.time;

    minutes = timeRemaining / 60;
    seconds = timeRemaining % 60;
    //miliSeconds = ?
    timeStr = minutes.ToString()+":"+seconds.ToString("D2");

    guiText.text = timeStr;
}
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: unityScript which is basically javascript but I just need logic so doesn't matter to which code you convert I think it will be fine

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, then try this code:

```
var startTime:float;
var timeRemaining:float;

var minutes:int;
var seconds:int;
var miliSeconds:int;
var timeStr:String;

function Start () {
    startTime = 130.0;
}

function Update () {
    timeRemaining = startTime - Time.time;

    minutes = timeRemaining / 60;
    seconds = timeRemaining;        
    miliSeconds = timeRemaining * 1000;

    seconds -= minutes*60;
    miliSeconds -= seconds*1000;

    timeStr = minutes.ToString()+":"+seconds.ToString("D2")+":"+miliSeconds.ToString();

    guiText.text = timeStr;
}
```

Comment: hey...thanks, it doesn't work. it got me forward though because now

Comment: hi...thanks, it doens't work. it got me forward though because now miliSeconds gets 129999 (when 129 seconds left) and so on

Comment: Correct, I've edited the code. I already thought of that myself but I was too quick with posting the code. Try my edit!

Comment: I edited again. I made the mistake of first extracting the seconds and afterwards the minutes. It should be the other way around.